# Getting errors in random functions that aren't being called upon launch

Tags: ios

So when I launch my app, I'll sometimes get an `EXC_BREAKPOINT` or `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` that points to a line within a function that's not being called. After writing some new, unrelated code, I can get these crashes without fail. And when I undo that code, I can sometimes rid of the error.But that code isn't at all related, and I'm not sure why I'm getting these errors in functions that aren't even being called.

I have a `UIWindow` with a custom `VideoPlayer` class that I'm returning upon launch. And the failing function is in that class, although it never gets called. Here's how I'm doing it:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    let player = VideoPlayer(frame:UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    var window: UIWindow? {
        set {

        }
        get {

            return player
        }
    }
}
```

Stack trace:

```
libswiftCore.dylib`function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded, Arg[1] = Exploded, Arg[2] = Dead, Arg[3] = Dead> of Swift._fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> ():
    0x1007cc740 <+0>:   stp    x29, x30, [sp, #-16]!
    0x1007cc744 <+4>:   mov    x29, sp
    0x1007cc748 <+8>:   sub    sp, sp, #16
    0x1007cc74c <+12>:  and    w8, w2, #0x1
    0x1007cc750 <+16>:  tbnz   w8, #0, 0x1007cc770       ; <+48>
    0x1007cc754 <+20>:  tbnz   x1, #63, 0x1007cc7b4      ; <+116>
    0x1007cc758 <+24>:  add    x1, x0, x1
    0x1007cc75c <+28>:  mov    x2, x3
    0x1007cc760 <+32>:  mov    x3, x4
    0x1007cc764 <+36>:  mov    x4, x5
    0x1007cc768 <+40>:  bl     0x10080edd0               ; function signature specialization <Arg[0] = Exploded, Arg[1] = Exploded> of Swift.(_fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> ()).(closure #2)
->  0x1007cc76c <+44>:  brk    #0x1
    0x1007cc770 <+48>:  str    xzr, [sp, #8]
    0x1007cc774 <+52>:  cmp    x0, w0, uxtw
    0x1007cc778 <+56>:  b.ne   0x1007cc94c               ; <+524>
    0x1007cc77c <+60>:  lsr    w8, w0, #11
    0x1007cc780 <+64>:  cmp    w8, #26
    0x1007cc784 <+68>:  b.hi   0x1007cc7d8               ; <+152>
    0x1007cc788 <+72>:  cmp    w0, #128
    0x1007cc78c <+76>:  b.lo   0x1007cc808               ; <+200>
    0x1007cc790 <+80>:  orr    w8, wzr, #0x80
    0x1007cc794 <+84>:  bfxil  x8, x0, #0, #6
    0x1007cc798 <+88>:  cmp    w0, #2048
    0x1007cc79c <+92>:  b.hs   0x1007cc83c               ; <+252>
    0x1007cc7a0 <+96>:  movz   x10, #0
    0x1007cc7a4 <+100>: movz   x11, #0
    0x1007cc7a8 <+104>: lsr    w9, w0, #6
    0x1007cc7ac <+108>: orr    w9, w9, #0xffffffc0
    0x1007cc7b0 <+112>: b      0x1007cc86c               ; <+300>
    0x1007cc7b4 <+116>: adr    x0, #808224               ; "fatal error"
    0x1007cc7b8 <+120>: nop    
    0x1007cc7bc <+124>: adr    x3, #808724               ; "UnsafeBufferPointer with negative count"
    0x1007cc7c0 <+128>: nop    
    0x1007cc7c4 <+132>: movz   w1, #0xb
    0x1007cc7c8 <+136>: orr    w2, wzr, #0x2
    0x1007cc7cc <+140>: movz   w4, #0x27
    0x1007cc7d0 <+144>: orr    w5, wzr, #0x2
    0x1007cc7d4 <+148>: bl     0x1007cc740               ; <+0>
    0x1007cc7d8 <+152>: cmp    w0, #14, lsl #12
    0x1007cc7dc <+156>: b.lo   0x1007cc818               ; <+216>
    0x1007cc7e0 <+160>: cmp    w0, #272, lsl #12
    0x1007cc7e4 <+164>: b.hs   0x1007cc900               ; <+448>
    0x1007cc7e8 <+168>: orr    w8, wzr, #0x80
    0x1007cc7ec <+172>: bfxil  x8, x0, #0, #6
    0x1007cc7f0 <+176>: orr    w9, wzr, #0xffffff80
    0x1007cc7f4 <+180>: bfxil  w9, w0, #6, #6
    0x1007cc7f8 <+184>: lsr    w10, w0, #16
    0x1007cc7fc <+188>: cbnz   w10, 0x1007cc924          ; <+484>
    0x1007cc800 <+192>: lsr    w10, w0, #12
    0x1007cc804 <+196>: b      0x1007cc848               ; <+264>
    0x1007cc808 <+200>: movz   x9, #0
    0x1007cc80c <+204>: movz   x11, #0
    0x1007cc810 <+208>: mov    x8, x0
    0x1007cc814 <+212>: b      0x1007cc89c               ; <+348>
    0x1007cc818 <+216>: adr    x0, #808124               ; "fatal error"
    0x1007cc81c <+220>: nop    
    0x1007cc820 <+224>: adr    x3, #811328               ; "high- and low-surrogate code points are not valid Unicode scalar values"
    0x1007cc824 <+228>: nop    
    0x1007cc828 <+232>: movz   w1, #0xb
    0x1007cc82c <+236>: orr    w2, wzr, #0x2
    0x1007cc830 <+240>: movz   w4, #0x47
    0x1007cc834 <+244>: orr    w5, wzr, #0x2
    0x1007cc838 <+248>: bl     0x1007cc740               ; <+0>
    0x1007cc83c <+252>: lsr    w10, w0, #12
    0x1007cc840 <+256>: orr    w9, wzr, #0xffffff80
    0x1007cc844 <+260>: bfxil  w9, w0, #6, #6
    0x1007cc848 <+264>: movz   x12, #0
    0x1007cc84c <+268>: movz   x11, #0
    0x1007cc850 <+272>: orr    w10, w10, #0xffffffe0
    0x1007cc854 <+276>: and    x10, x10, #0xff
    0x1007cc858 <+280>: lsl    x13, x12, #3
    0x1007cc85c <+284>: lsl    x10, x10, x13
    0x1007cc860 <+288>: orr    x11, x10, x11
    0x1007cc864 <+292>: str    x11, [sp, #8]
    0x1007cc868 <+296>: add    x10, x12, #1
    0x1007cc86c <+300>: orr    w12, wzr, #0x8
    0x1007cc870 <+304>: umulh  x12, x10, x12
    0x1007cc874 <+308>: cmp    xzr, x12
    0x1007cc878 <+312>: b.ne   0x1007cc94c               ; <+524>
    0x1007cc87c <+316>: lsl    x12, x10, #3
    0x1007cc880 <+320>: cmp    x12, #63
    0x1007cc884 <+324>: b.hi   0x1007cc8dc               ; <+412>
    0x1007cc888 <+328>: and    x9, x9, #0xff
    0x1007cc88c <+332>: lsl    x9, x9, x12
    0x1007cc890 <+336>: orr    x11, x9, x11
    0x1007cc894 <+340>: str    x11, [sp, #8]
    0x1007cc898 <+344>: add    x9, x10, #1
    0x1007cc89c <+348>: orr    w10, wzr, #0x8
    0x1007cc8a0 <+352>: umulh  x10, x9, x10
    0x1007cc8a4 <+356>: cmp    xzr, x10
    0x1007cc8a8 <+360>: b.ne   0x1007cc94c               ; <+524>
    0x1007cc8ac <+364>: lsl    x10, x9, #3
    0x1007cc8b0 <+368>: cmp    x10, #64
    0x1007cc8b4 <+372>: b.hs   0x1007cc8dc               ; <+412>
    0x1007cc8b8 <+376>: and    x8, x8, #0xff
    0x1007cc8bc <+380>: lsl    x8, x8, x10
    0x1007cc8c0 <+384>: orr    x8, x8, x11
    0x1007cc8c4 <+388>: str    x8, [sp, #8]
    0x1007cc8c8 <+392>: add    x8, sp, #8
    0x1007cc8cc <+396>: add    x8, x9, x8
    0x1007cc8d0 <+400>: add    x1, x8, #1
    0x1007cc8d4 <+404>: add    x0, sp, #8
    0x1007cc8d8 <+408>: b      0x1007cc75c               ; <+28>
    0x1007cc8dc <+412>: adr    x0, #807928               ; "fatal error"
    0x1007cc8e0 <+416>: nop    
    0x1007cc8e4 <+420>: adr    x3, #808332               ; "shift amount is larger than type size in bits"
    0x1007cc8e8 <+424>: nop    
    0x1007cc8ec <+428>: movz   w1, #0xb
    0x1007cc8f0 <+432>: orr    w2, wzr, #0x2
    0x1007cc8f4 <+436>: movz   w4, #0x2d
    0x1007cc8f8 <+440>: orr    w5, wzr, #0x2
    0x1007cc8fc <+444>: bl     0x1007cc740               ; <+0>
    0x1007cc900 <+448>: adr    x0, #807892               ; "fatal error"
    0x1007cc904 <+452>: nop    
    0x1007cc908 <+456>: adr    x3, #811176               ; "value is outside of Unicode codespace"
    0x1007cc90c <+460>: nop    
    0x1007cc910 <+464>: movz   w1, #0xb
    0x1007cc914 <+468>: orr    w2, wzr, #0x2
    0x1007cc918 <+472>: movz   w4, #0x25
    0x1007cc91c <+476>: orr    w5, wzr, #0x2
    0x1007cc920 <+480>: bl     0x1007cc740               ; <+0>
    0x1007cc924 <+484>: lsr    w10, w0, #18
    0x1007cc928 <+488>: orr    w11, w10, #0xf0
    0x1007cc92c <+492>: cmp    w11, w11, uxtb
    0x1007cc930 <+496>: b.ne   0x1007cc94c               ; <+524>
    0x1007cc934 <+500>: orr    w10, wzr, #0xffffff80
    0x1007cc938 <+504>: bfxil  w10, w0, #12, #6
    0x1007cc93c <+508>: and    x11, x11, #0xff
    0x1007cc940 <+512>: str    x11, [sp, #8]
    0x1007cc944 <+516>: orr    w12, wzr, #0x1
    0x1007cc948 <+520>: b      0x1007cc854               ; <+276>
    0x1007cc94c <+524>: brk    #0x1
```

**Why is a line within a function that's not being called causing a crash?**

Comment: Where is the app crashing? Have you set an exception breakpoint to catch it? What does the stack trace show? Also, can you show the full error log.

Comment: App is crashing immediately on launch. And I'm getting `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value`. But this is all within a function that's not being called.

Comment: Please see http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug a crash.

Comment: @dperk you need to add an exception breakpoint. It will show you the line of code that is crashing. You have probably put a ! Somewhere where there is a nil value. Go to the break points tab and hit the + button to add an exception breakpoint.

Comment: Yeah I did all of that. I'm not force unwrapping any optionals on that line, though. I haven't modified anything that has to do with the variables called either.

Comment: My question is really regarding why a line within a function that's not being called is causing a crash.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information. Post the code that is showing the error, indicate where the debugger shows the line as if it's executing, and then explain the flow of your program. The stack trace is deep inside system frameworks, making it all but useless to sort out what's going on.

Comment: Check all the links between the interface and the code. When I delete, as an example, an IBOutlet from the code and remove it from the view, i get that same error.